# Expected value and Variance of $Y = \max(X, 2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, variance, uniform-distribution

**Problem:** Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution under $[0,4]$ and $Y = \max(X,2)$. Find:

- $P(Y<3)$
- Expected value of $Y$
- Variance of $Y$

**Attempted solution:**

$$ F_Y(3) = P(Y<3) = P(\max(X,2)<3) = P(X<3)P(2<3) = \frac{3}{4} $$

Since $F_X(3) = \frac{3-0}{4-0}$.

I am highly suspicious of this answer. What is the best approach to finding the expected value and variance of $Y$?

Comment: It makes sense to rewrite $Y$ in terms of indicator variables: $Y=2\cdot\mathbb 1_{\{X\leq2\}}+X\cdot 1_{\{X> 2\}}.$

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). You may also want to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If $X \sim U(0,4)$, then the pdf of $X$ is $f:[0,4] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}$.

As $Y=\max(X,2)$, $Y= \begin{cases}
       X, &  \hspace{2mm} X>2 \\
       2, & \hspace{2mm} X \leq 2\\
     \end{cases}$

$\qquad\begin{align}P(Y<3)&=P(0 \le X<3)\\&=\int_{0}^{3}f(x)dx\\&=\int_{0}^{3}\frac{1}{4}dx\\&=(3-0)\frac{1}{4}
\\&=\frac{3}{4}
\\[2ex]
E(Y)&=E(X\mid X>2)~P(X>2)+2~P(X\le 2)\\&=\int_{2}^{4}\frac{x}{4}dx+2\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{4}dx\\&=\frac{20}{8}
\\[2ex]
E(Y^2)&=\int_{2}^{4}\frac{x^2}{4}dx+4\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{4}dx\\&=\frac{80}{12}
\\[2ex]
\therefore\quad Var(Y)&=\frac{80}{12}-(\frac{20}{8})^2\\&=\frac{5}{12}\end{align}$

Comment: You really should not do *all* the work, @Karam .